# C# Synchronize Wait / Poll methods

Tags: .net, multithreading, synchronization

I have a class that exposes two methods:

- `GetObject`

Gets a single object, or returns null if there are none.

- `WaitForObject`

Gets a single object, or waits until their is one.

An example implementation:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        MyStack stack;
        public object GetObject()
        {
            return stack.Pop();
        }
        public object WaitForObject()
        {
            object returnValue;
            while (returnValue == null)
                returnValue = stack.Pop()
            return returnValue
        }
    }
```

With the assumption that `MyStack` is thread safe, how can I make `MyClass` thread safe? I.e.

- `GetObject` should never block
 - `Thread` doing `WaitForObject` should get any new objects added to the stack instead of `GetObject`.

For bonus points, how can users adding objects to the stack notify any listeners that a new object is available? (eliminating the need for polling)

Comment: @Martin - Sorry, I wrote this on my phone.

Comment: If you're on .NET 4, you can just use `BlockingCollection<object>`, passing a `ConcurrentStack<object>` into its constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If `MyStack` is guaranteed to be thread safe then `MyClass` is also thread safe. In the two methods you are using only local variables so the methods are reentrant.

Currently users cannot add objects to the stack because the `stack` field is not visible outside the class. Also I don't see from your code how do listeners will subscribe to any events so that they are notified if an object is added. So you could have a method allowing to add elements to the stack and an event that will be triggered in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can achieve everything with Monitor functionality. just a sketch

```
class MyClass
{
    private Stack<object> stack = new Stack<object>();
    public object GetObject()
    {
        lock(stack)
        {
            return stack.Count != 0 ? stack.Pop() : null;
        }
    }
    public object WaitForObject()
    {
        lock (stack)
        {
            if (stack.Count == 0)
            {
                // wait until PutObject is called
                Monitor.Wait(stack);
            }

            return stack.Pop();
        }
    }

    public void PutObject(object obj)
    {
        lock (stack)
        {
            stack.Push(obj);
            // notify one thread blocked by WaitForObject call
            Monitor.Pulse(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Polling usually involves some form of sleep - the loop in your example would be a tight loop that would throttle the thead all the time.  Add a `Thread.Sleep(100)` call, or some other sensible value, to poll over time.

The other way to wait would be to register a callback, or have the stack expose a blocking `Pop` method, either way, these would be implemented in the `Stack` class in your example.

**Bonus Answer:** Your class would need to expose an event, when they add an object to the stack, it would fire this event.

```
class MyClass 
    { 
        MyStack stack; 
        public object GetObject() 
        { 
            return stack.Pop(); 
        } 
        public object WaitForObject() 
        { 
            object returnValue; 
            while (returnValue == null) 
                returnValue = stack.Pop() 
            return returnValue 
        } 
        public void AddObject(object o)
        {
            stack.Push(o);
            OnObjectAdded();
        }
        public event EventHandler ObjectAdded;

        private void OnObjectAdded()
        {
            if (ObjectAdded != null)
                ObjectAdded(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Busy waiting with Thread.Sleep is a bad idea. Use a timer or a callback as you mention.

Comment: This callback would have to be implemented on the underlying collection (ie, his Stack). Assuming a System.Threading.Timer or a System.Timer, then the tick of the timer would not be guaranteed to run on the same thread. This is not necessarily a problem, but it might not be desirable.

Comment: @Mikael I usually agree, but to keep the polling on the same thread, unfortunately there aren't many options.