# Ideal data polling method?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have to continuously poll data from an external board via USB. How should I go about doing this in the scripting side? Is there any threading concept or something else? The data has to be polled every 20 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

For connecting to the USB here is an example:
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/

For C# Synchronize Wait / Poll methods:
[C# Synchronize Wait / Poll methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381140/c-sharp-synchronize-wait-poll-methods)

Sorry I couldn’t be more helpful. If you provide more information it might make a solution more oblivious.

Comment: Did this help you? or do you need more info